# How to implement routed tabs with angular material, within a child route?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-router

I want to use Angular Material tabs https://material.angular.io/components/tabs with a router navigation in the tabs.

I tried to use `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>` as indicated in the doc, and I found this tutorial: https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2018/10/27/Angular-Material-Tabs-with-Router/
where I can find a template like that:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
    [routerLink]="link.link"
    routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But the problem is, that my tabs are not at the root of my application, but are in a submodule in a child route. I have something like that:

In app-routing-module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'subpath', loadChildren: () => import('./path-to-module/submodule.module').then(m => m.SubmoduleModule) },
  ...
];
```

In submodule-routing-module I should have something like that:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: FirstTabComponent },
  { path: 'tab2', component: SecondTabComponent },
]
```

What I would like is that, if I go to url `/subpath` I see the tabs with the first tab selected, and if I go to url `/subpath/tab2` I see the tabs with the second tab selected.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: Not really... I used a workaround, not using the Angular router but managing the tab's routes manually...

Comment: @S.Caruso Does the answer of janders meet your requirements? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60367203/1065654

Answer (score 14):

I, too, ran into the same issue. I cloned [Angular-Material-Tabs-with-Router](https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2018/10/27/Angular-Material-Tabs-with-Router/) but modified it with a child component that also has child components.

The child component is called `home` and in `home.component.html` it implements:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
  *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
  [routerLink]="link.link"
  routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
  [active]="rla.isActive">
  {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This creates 3 tabs called `Notes`, `Photos` and `Documents`. The `Notes` tab includes additional components to list, view, edit and delete notes.

I created and added the source to GitHub and imported it to Stackblitz:

[GitHub](https://github.com/janders/angular-tab-router-with-children)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/janders/angular-tab-router-with-children)

Comment: OP wanted the first tab selected when not in a child of the tabs page which your example does not do. I just threw a `this.router.navigate(['subPathToFirstTab'], { relativeTo: this.route });` at the end of `ngOnInit` and it works nicely. (Injecting `private route: ActivatedRoute` in the constructor.)

Comment: @StackUnderflow Good catch, but your solution has a bug. If you open another link directly (e.g. click on the second tab and reload the page), you get navigated to the first link/tab. However, you should stay at the child of the tabs page in this case (in my example the second tab).

Answer (score 3):

If my understanding is right, you want to navigate to a component in a lazy loaded module.

For this I made a stackblitz, which might be useful for you.

Here's the basic code for your understanding

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar class="mat-elevation-z8" >
  <a
    mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
    routerLink="{{ link.location }}"
    routerLinkActive
    #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive"
  >
    <mat-icon>{{ link.icon }}</mat-icon>
    <span>{{ link.label | uppercase }}</span>
  </a>
</nav>
```

in ts

```
 navLinks = [
    {location:'',label:'dummy',icon:'menu'},
    { location: '/shared', label: 'Overview', icon: 'account_circle' },
    { location: '/shared/sub', label: 'Experience', icon: 'work' }
  ];
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwnijt?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts)

Comment: Hello, your stackblitz seems not to have anything to do with material tabs... Is it the correct one?

Comment: Updated stckblitz link, check once

Comment: Thanks, the stackblitz is the right one now. But infortunately this doesn't meet my needs: my tabs component should also be in the lazy loaded module, not in the root module...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
The problem came from the routing module.

In order to inherit the imported Material classes,
the path for children must be lazy-loaded instead of being directed from the component.

This caused the problem:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    // Don't use this method in order to link to children!
    component: 'CustomerListComponent'

  }
```

The 'customer list' template loaded, but without formatting. Also, Angular threw an error because it could not find the '*mat-tab*' directive anywhere, even though it was being imported in the parent component, `orders.module.ts`.

**This was the solution:** `src > app > app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [{
      path: 'customers',
      loadChildren: () =>
        import ('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
    }
```

Here are the related files from the project:
`src > app > orders > orders.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { OrdersRoutingModule } from './orders-routing.module';
import { OrderListComponent } from './order-list/order-list.component';

// Material components
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OrdersRoutingModule,
    MatTabsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    OrderListComponent
  ]
})
export class OrdersModule { }
```

`src > app > orders > orders-list > orders-list.component.html`

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Orders">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <p>Orders here.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Shipments">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <p>Shipments here.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Archived">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <p>Really old orders here.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: This is regular tab implementation. OP asked for routed tabs though.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to **janders** solution is to use the router dependency. With `router.url()`function, you are able to compare the current active url with your navigation links.

In your `Component.ts`:

```
...

rootUrl = '/path/to/your/component';

  navigation = [
    {
      name: 'Table',
      link: '',
    },
    {
      name: 'Stats',
      link: '/stats',
    },
    {
      name: 'Settings',
      link: '/settings',
    },
    {
      name: 'Export',
      link: '/export',
    }
  ];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) {
...
}

...
```

In your `Component.html`:

```
...

  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="left">
    <a mat-tab-link
       *ngFor="let l of navigation"
       [routerLink]="rootUrl + l.link"
       [active]="this.router.url === rootUrl + l.link">
      {{l.name}}
    </a>
  </nav>

...
```

In your router:

```
...

  {
    path: '/path/to/your/component',
    component: Component,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path:'',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: TableComponent
      },
      {
        path:'settings',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: SettingsComponent
      },
      {
        path:'export',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: ExportComponent
      },
      {
        path:'stats',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: StatsComponent
      }
    ]
  }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

the same code previously see, but updated

```
************* code updated ********  (12-05-2022, version angular recent)
              <nav mat-tab-nav-bar >
                      <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
                               (click)="activeLink = link.link"
                               [routerLink]="link.link"
                               [active]="activeLink == link.link"> {{link.label}} </a>
                    </nav>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```