# Angular 10 material tabs: select tab based on route parameter?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-router

I have a page with a `mat-tab-group`, which is at the route `/transactions`.

```
      <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Shipments">
          <ng-template matTabContent>
            shipment content
          </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Refunds">
          <ng-template matTabContent>
            Refund content
          </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Backorders">
          <ng-template matTabContent>
            Backorders content
          </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
     </mat-tab-group>
```

I would like to be able to select which tab is shown with a route parameter, so that I could link to `/transactions/refunds` or `/transactions/?type='refunds'` or something similar and navigate to the transactions page with the appropriate tab being active.

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921846/how-to-implement-routed-tabs-with-angular-material-within-a-child-route/57925535#57925535

Comment: I saw that but it looked more like using tabs to navigate to routes instead of the reverse. I’ll look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case use selectedIndex input of mat-tab-group (see https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api).

The overall concept may look as follows.

In .html:

`<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">`

In .ts:

```
selectedIndex = 0;

navItems = [
    { label: 'Label 1', route: '/route1' },
    { label: 'Label 2', route: '/route2' }
];

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(
        () => (
          this.selectedIndex = this.navItems.findIndex(
            nav => nav.route === this.router.url
          )
      )
    );
  }
```